# Does Windows 7 include a CHM Helpfile viewer?

Tags: windows-7, documentation, chm, viewer

Does Windows 7 have a CHM viewer preinstalled? Windows Vista didn't have one, so helpfiles of most regular software could not be viewed.

Comment: What are you talking about?  Vista does have a built-in CHM viewer.

I say this as a guy who gets paid to write help files.  They're all in CHM format and work fine with Vista.

Comment: With Windows Vista, Microsoft dropped support for WinHelp (*.hlp). But if you tried to actually view a .hlp file you would be presented with a page where you could download it. Compiled HTML (chm) files are **no**t depricated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Windows 7 includes a CHM viewer:

[image]

Vista had one as well as CarlF mentioned in the comments; maybe there was something wrong with your installation?

Comment: Maybe Jeremy made a mistake with the .hlp files, the older format for help files. Vista did not have a program to open them, nor had Windows 7. Microsoft released an update for both OSes to add back this support. It's very recent for Win7 and available here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=258aa5ec-e3d9-4228-8844-008e02b32a2c

Comment: Possibly, but he said CHM in the title so I went off of that.